# Running startproject on django-admin runs, but no directories are being made

Tags: python, django, windows

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on the Django website, so I tried to make a project using `django-admin startproject mysite`. The command runs without error, but when I open the directory the project it's supposed to be stored in, the directory is completely empty. Running the command again gives me the following: `CommandError: 'G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial\mysite' already exists`.

I read on some other posts where it might be related to having multiple installs and the commands running and conflicting, so I removed all the references to my other Python versions (except 3.8). It still doesn't seem to do anything.

I made a different folder to see if it's just some weird folder conflict (There used to be another django project in the same folder before I deleted it; I wanted to start the tutorial again). However, still no files are being created.

I'm pretty stumped by this. Does it have anything to do with my Python installs or a previous Django installation (I tried running `pip uninstall django` twice, but it only ran once on my current Django installation).

I'm using Django 3.0.1 currently, on Windows 10. Thanks

This is my cmd output upon request:

```
G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial>python -V
Python 3.8.0

G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial>python3 -V
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial>dir
 Volume in drive G is Files

 Directory of G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial

26/12/2019  06:40 PM    <DIR>          .
26/12/2019  06:40 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  64,085,245,952 bytes free

G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial>django-admin startproject myapp

G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial>dir
 Volume in drive G is Files

 Directory of G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial

26/12/2019  06:40 PM    <DIR>          .
26/12/2019  06:40 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  64,085,245,952 bytes free

G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial>cd myapp
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

**Update on virtualenvs:**
Following suggestions, I installed virtualenv. Upon running `virtualenv env`, the `env/` folder didn't show up, in the same manner Django did when it was making its project.
I also tried running venv, which made the env folder (I did this in a separate folder). I installed and ran Django on that, but the directory is still empty.

Console output below:

```
G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial>pip install virtualenv
<Insert pip stuff here>
Successfully installed virtualenv-16.7.9


G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial>virtualenv env
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\kenshin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38'
New python executable in G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial\env\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial>env\Scripts\activate
The system cannot find the path specified.

G:\PROGRAMS\django-tutorial>source env\Scripts\activate
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

# I made a new folder after this point

G:\PROGRAMS\envtest>virtualenv env
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\kenshin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38'
New python executable in G:\PROGRAMS\envtest\env\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

G:\PROGRAMS\envtest>dir
 Volume in drive G is Files

 Directory of G:\PROGRAMS\envtest

26/12/2019  07:53 PM    <DIR>          .
26/12/2019  07:53 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  64,085,245,952 bytes free

# venv test

G:\PROGRAMS\envtest>python -m venv env

G:\PROGRAMS\envtest>env\Scripts\activate

(env) G:\PROGRAMS\envtest>pip install Django==3.0.1
<It worked>

(env) G:\PROGRAMS\envtest>django-admin startproject mysite

(env) G:\PROGRAMS\envtest>dir
 Volume in drive G is Files

 Directory of G:\PROGRAMS\envtest

26/12/2019  07:56 PM    <DIR>          .
26/12/2019  07:56 PM    <DIR>          ..
26/12/2019  07:56 PM    <DIR>          env
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  64,071,540,736 bytes free
```

Comment: Probably virtual environment error. Are you doing it right?

Comment: I haven't opened my folder in a virtual environment, just in cmd.

Comment: Have you created one?

Comment: @SrijwalR might be right, can you try those commands again?

Comment: Tried running them, virtualenv's "env" folder never appeared. venv seemed to make the env, but startproject still seems to be a bust. I updated to post to reflect my attempts

Comment: This seems vague but why don't you try some other directory, Desktop for instance.
Also make sure that you run your command prompt as admin. 
If that doesn't work as well, try this with powershell if still no luck then maybe check your environment variables once. and at last, if nothing works, download linux bash shell from the windows store and try in it. (I usually reinstall my OS if something like this happens, its so frustrating)

Comment: May the Force Be With You!

Answer (score 0):

can you type the following commands and share the output?

```
dir
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install django
django-admin startproject myapp
dir
cd myapp
dir
```